# Add object with a defined width in a StackView

Tags: swift, progress-bar, constraints, uistackview

I'm facing a logical problems with StackView and I know where I have to search answers.
So I have a stackView, with 3 elems in it, 2 labels and a progress bar,
And I want my progress bar to have a fixed size, but from now my progress bar took the width of the biggest label.
I try to add a width constraint on it, but if my label has a text longer than progress bar's width, my label text is ended by "..."

And I want that, whatever the text of the label is, my progress bar has **ALWAYS** the same width.

my code is :

```
myStackView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
make.centerX.equalTo(myView)
make.centerY.equalTo(myView)
}
myLabelAboveProgressBar.text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
myStackView.addArrangedSubview(myLabelAboveProgressBar)
myProgressBar.setPercentage(20, animted: false)
myStackView.addArrangedSubview(myProgressBar)
```

Comment: By any chances, isn't that just a problem with the numberOfLines of the label not set to 0?

Comment: No you don't get the problem, the label is not the problem, it's the progress bar which is the problem

Comment: I want my progress bar, whatever the text label, to get always have the same width

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the alignment of your stack view is defaulting to 'fill'. You can change this as follows:

```
myStackView.alignment = .Center
```

...or whatever you want the alignment to be such as leading, trailing, etc

The same applies to the distribution:

```
myStackView.distribution = .FillEqually
```

...for instance. You also have other options like FillEqually, EqualSpacing, etc

You may also want to set a fixed width (or relative to screen size) for your stack view so that your layout is a bit more predictable. Sounds like it's scaling to fit the contents at the moment.

Comment: I followed your advices and try to change some properties of my stack view, but none of them seems to work as I want.
If I create constraint of leading/trailing on my stackView, that'll cut the label text, and I don't want that. I only want to have a small progress bar under my label, whatever the text is, and whatever the percentage is.
When I put the Center alignment my progress bar disappears...

Comment: Hi @Chris sorry to answer you now.
I've tried another solution, in my solution, I create a stackView that contains only the progressBars, so I have the 4 progressBars with the same width, and I put the label above manually.
Thanks for your answer !